# Using a windows kernal function via GetModuleHandle

Tags: c++, windows, kernel-module

I would like to use FsRtlIsDbcsInExpression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546803(v=vs.85).aspx) to do wild card checking exactly the same as Windows does it natively without have to re-implement it in my program.  When I use:

```
auto module = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("NtosKrnl.exe"));
```

module turns up null.  From what I can find on the internet, since this is a kernel mode function, KernelGetModuleBase is required.  However, this function doesn't seem to resolve automatically and there are no msdn docs on it, so I am doubtful that is the solution.  Does anyone have pointers for how to use function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetModuleHandle for ntoskrnl is going to fail because it's not loaded into your memory space. You can only call such functions from kernel.

You might want to try for the function PathMatch spec (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It appears to do the same job.

Comment: This fixed the issue!